# Asking a simple Y/N question and return values based on answer

Tags: python

I am sure is a very silly question but I am somewhat new to python.

My question is fairly simple. I want to ask the user whether some default values should be loaded or whether some new one would be inserted.

I have defined the function below and I am then calling it later. I have only included the if statement for the yes answers. My issue is that the defined values are not actually being returned as when I call another function that uses those values later on it says it has invalid inputs.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help!

```
def load_default(question):
    yes = {"y", "yes"} 
    no = {"n", "no"}
    sys.stdout.write(question)
    choice = input().lower
    if choice in yes:
            S0 = 40
            K = 50
            r = 0.1
            sigma = 0.1
            T = 10
            return S0, K, r, sigma, T


load_default("Load default values (Y) or insert new ones manually (N)?")
```

Comment: `input().lower` is a function. `input().lower()` is a string. Closing as typo.

Comment: A simple print-debugging, like `print(choice)` after the input statement should have been useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe with choice=input().lower() vs choice=input().lower

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell what version of python are you using? Because the other answers wont work for python 2.x